# How to debug TCP connection between MATLAB and C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, tcp

I have a MATLAB script that communicates via pnet mex file with an executable built via C++ using winsock library. The C++ executable streams data off of a device and then transmits that data into MATLAB via TCP. Every so often, MATLAB hangs or crashes during communication. I'd like to find out why this is happening and fix the problem but I'm not sure how to go about debugging a process in which a MATLAB script is calling on multiple executables of multiple languages (MATLAB and C++) that are working together simultaneously.

How would you suggest I go about debugging this entire communication process?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: Hi Ratbert, the program is fairly large, spanning multiple m files. Any particular part of the program you need to see? I just want to know how I'd debug. Don't necessairily need someone to debug. Thanks!